# java clear (not close) InputStream

Tags: java, parsing, inputstream, interactive

I wrote a server/client application in java. Now I have to create a testing component to interact with the server interactively. The testing component itself consists of a class to handle client-instances (a ProcessBuilder for each one).

Now to the problem: to parse the server-responses (find the end of the response), I close the specific lines within escape sequences  (e.g. \t\b). This works as expected, but before I send a specific command to the server, I have to clear the InputStream (discard all things within the stream, like log-entries, status-msg and so on).

```
//input=process.getInputStream();
//out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

public String send(String command){
    log.info("execute: " + command);

    try{
        //clear old output
        int chars = input.available();

        log.info("Skip " + chars + " characters from process output.");
        input.skip(chars);

        out.write(command + "\n");
        out.flush();

    }catch (IOException e){
        log.error("could not write to process", e);
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    String line;

    try {
        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
            log.info("new line " + line);

            if(line.contains("\t\b")){
                //skip others
                input.skip(input.available());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str.toString();
}
```

But this doesn't work.

**Example Output**

```
0    [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - ClientHandler started 1543748404 (localhost 9000 )
6    [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - execute: somecommand
 6    [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - Skip 0 characters from process output.
 112  [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - new line Connection successfully
 113  [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - new line no entries available\t\b
```

"Connection successfully" should be discarded.

```
113  [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - execute: somecommand
 113  [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - Skip 0 characters from process output.
 114  [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - new line no entries available\t\b

114  [main] INFO  Test  - Test: close
 114  [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - ClientHandler Closed 1543748404
 114  [main] INFO  loadtesting.ClientHandler  - und ciao
```

**Update**
I found the problem, but no solution. It's because the available method of InputStream always returns 0:

> The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.

Now I will search for an child of IS, who implements available().

Comment: InputStream.available mostly does not what you expect. I went down that road.

Comment: Any tipps? What to use instead?

Comment: Instead of just an end-token, you could use a start and an end-token. So you can Sync on "start" and then read to "end" and just discard everything in between.